# Floor vent under stove, does it need to be moved?

Tags: hvac, ventilation, oven

I am remodeling my kitchen and have a floor vent (hvac) that used to be in the space where the cabinets overhang the floor.  Not sure what it's called...the space where your feet can go under the cabinets.

The spot used to have a built in range (the oven was separate) so it wasn't a problem. In out remodeling we are replacing all that with a free standing range/oven combo.

Problem being that now the floor vent would be directly under the oven.

**Can I just put a vent cover on it, and angle the vent to blow out and leave it underneath the oven or do I need to reroute the ductwork and find another place to move it?**

[This is the oven](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HJOY8MK)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Moving would be better as freestanding ranges set very close to the floor. You would only have about one inch of clearance to redirect the discharge of the vent opening to blow from beneath the range. I am sure you could fabricate a diverter of some sort but being only one inch in height, the discharge velocity would be loud and you could definitely feel it on your feet while standing at the range.
Again, it would probably be easier to relocate. BTW, the space at the bottom of your cabinets is called the "toekick."

Comment: Thanks, it was driving me nuts that I couldn't think of the name.

Comment: Upvote - ranges indeed are very close to the floor and the wall so you really won't have the room to externally divert that duct.

Comment: If you can get to that duct, just move it to another location, In a wall,  floor ,etc.